# Custom Rest Endpoint: Post/Put/Patch not working

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api

I'm trying to get a custom rest api working to handle some stuff. One part I need to do requires a Post/Put to the API.

But the API-call always goes 404 on me and I have no idea why. I've registered a test route as follows

```
register_rest_route('test/v1', 'test', array(
    'method' => WP_REST_Server::ALLMETHODS,
    'callback' => function () {
        return current_user_can("test_metadata_edit");
    },
    'permission_callback' => function () {
        return true;
    }
));
```

And I create a nonce for the Post/Put request via an inline script:

```
wp_add_inline_script("test_script", 'var nonce = "' . wp_create_nonce('wp_rest') . '"');
```

up until here everything works fine.

Now I try to GET the endpoint, which works. If I supply no nonce at all, it returns false. If a user is logged in and I use the generated nonce either via `_wpnonce=` or the `X-WP-Nonce`-header, it returns the correct result for the users capability. But if I try to Post, Put or Patch it always returns a 404 and I have absolutely no clue why. If I create a nonce for a logged out user though, I get a 403 instead.

```
fetch('/wp-json/test/v1/test', { method: 'GET', headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': '12345'}}) //works
fetch('/wp-json/test/v1/test?_wpnonce=12345', { method: 'GET'}}) //works
fetch('/wp-json/test/v1/test', { method: 'POST', headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': '12345'}) //does not work, 404
fetch('/wp-json/test/v1/test?_wpnonce=12345', { method: 'PUT' }) //also doesn't work, 404
```

Any ideas as to what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'method'` argument for `register_rest_route()` should be named `'methods'`. Because of the typo, the argument is interpreted as it's default value - `'GET'` only.

Comment: This... is so unbelievable stupidly simple... But I didn't see it and probably wouldn't anytime soon. So thanks for sharper eyes than mine :D

Comment: No problem :) . Doesn't help that the dev hub hasn't really documented the argument yet!